# .htaccess redirect on 404 on specific directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm using wordpress with Avada theme. Every new theme update a new js file is created in /wp-content/uploads/fusion-scripts/

```
/wp-content/uploads/fusion-scripts/8ca1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa.min.js
/wp-content/uploads/fusion-scripts/d83hhxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa.min.js
/wp-content/uploads/fusion-scripts/edij3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.min.js
```

I cannot control their filenames. Those files are included in the mainpage. Googlebots for example learns those paths and after a theme update it fails because it continues to use the old filenames and gets 404.

I have problems with my security plugin because I'm not able to whitelist /wp-content/uploads/fusion-scripts/ so it is possibile that it bans googlebot.
I would add to my .htaccess something in order to redirect the request to /wp-content/uploads/mytest/a.js which is static and prevent to ban scrapers which uses old cache names

Is it possible?
Riccardo

Comment: I guess robots.txt file will help. It will help you manage which link should be crawled.

Comment: goto this link https://neilpatel.com/blog/robots-txt/

Comment: But googlebot should crawl /wp-content/uploads/fusion-scripts/